# Paper wallet vs wallet.dat on memory stick for long term storage?

Tags: wallet, offline

What does everyone think? Also what are the advantages and disadvantages of each one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Paper wallet:**

*pros:*

- easy to store
- easy to create
- provide the same amount of security as the fiat money does
- you don't need to worry about viruses
- valid for a long time

*cons:*

- easy to be misplaced
- if you cannot provide phisical security, it is more likely useless

**wallet.dat on pendrive**

*pros:*

- none, in my opinion

*cons:*

- easy to be misplaced
- pendrive can become corrupted in the next few years, due to hardware deterioration
- it can easly be stolen or copied
- again, you need to provide phisical security
- wallet.dat format can change over time, thus making your data hard to recover (depends on the future decision of devs)

Comment: pro pendrive: More convenient re-import of wallet.dat, compared to typing or scanning from paper

Comment: Actually... no. What is more convinient for you? Scanning a QR code / typing private key into Btc client, or merge 2 wallet.dat (it is non-trivial using standard BitcoinQT client)?

Comment: I suppose it might depend on your situation. I would have assumed you'd be replacing the (unused) wallet.dat, but I see your point, too.